# Изменение текста на странице HTML с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такой скрипт:

```js
  function latin() {
   document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/А/g, 'A').replace(/а/g, 'a').replace(/Ә/g, 'Á').replace(/ә/g, 'á').replace(/Б/g, 'B').replace(/б/g, 'b');
  }

  function cyrilic() {
   document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/А/g, 'A').replace(/а/g, 'a').replace(/Á/g, 'Ә').replace(/á/g, 'ә').replace(/B/g, 'Б').replace(/b/g, 'б');
  }
```

```html
<p>А а Ә ә Б б</p> 
<button onclick='latin()'>Латинский</button>
<button onclick='cyrilic()'>Кириллица</button>
```

Что делать, если при нажатии на "Латинский" всё изменяется нормально, а при нажатии на "Кириллица" выходит код кнопки, при этом если я пишу код для изменения всех букв по алфавиту, у меня ещё и выходит код функции

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код делает больше, чем вы, вероятно думаете. Он меняет весь html документа, на тот же html, меняя в нём буквы. При замене `b` а `б`, ваш тег `button` превращается в `бutton` и браузер просто не понимает его.

Я думаю вам надо менять не весь документ вместе с кнопками, а только область с текстом.

- Получите элемент с текстом `var p = document.querySelector('p');`
- Используйте его свойство innerHTML `p.innerHTML = ...`

Comment: Нет, мне просто нужно сделать функцию для замены букв на всей странице сайта. Каждый блок, каждую таблицу, совершенно все буквы нужно заменять, при этом нужно чтобы всё выглядело нормально, то есть без ошибок

Comment: Сделал, как вы и сказали, но так не работает

Comment: @НаильЯрулин если надо менять текст на всей странице (включая кнопки), то вам надо работать только с текстовыми нодами иначе вы будете портить html.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю сделать примерно так:

UPD: исправил с учетом изменения содержимого всех элементов на странице.

```js
var transformConfig = {
  latin: [
    ['А', 'A'],
    ['a', 'a'],
    ['Ә', 'Á'],
    ['ә', 'á'],
    ['Б', 'B'],
    ['б', 'b'],
  ],
  cyrillic: [
    ['А', 'A'],
    ['а', 'a'],
    ['Á', 'Ә'],
    ['á', 'ә'],
    ['B', 'Б'],
    ['b', 'б'],
  ]
};

function transform(type) {
  // выполняем дальше если есть такое свойство
  if (typeof transformConfig[type] !== 'undefined') {
    // находим все элементы на странице
    var collection = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
    // перебираем все элементы на странице
    for (var idx = 0; idx < collection.length; idx++) {
      element = collection[idx];
      // если у элемента есть свойство innerHTML, идем дальше
      if (typeof element.innerHTML !== 'undefined') {
        transformConfig[type].forEach(function(chars) {

          var pattern = new RegExp(
            chars[0],
            'g'
          );
          // изменяем innerHTML
          element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(
            pattern,
            chars[1]
          )
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p>А а Ә ә Б б</p>
<div>А а Ә ә Б б</div>
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">А а Ә ә Б б</a>
<br>
<button onclick="transform('latin')">Латинский</button>
<button onclick="transform('cyrillic')">Кириллица</button>
```

Comment: А что делать с классами, span и т.д., у меня всё равно это появляется((